# change user password using shell_exec function

Tags: shell-exec, passwd

I have created a new user and password. Now I need to change the username and password from the web page. I am able to change the username using usermod.
But I am not able to change to password using the passwd command.
Here the code:

```
shell_exec('(echo "'.$FTPpassword.'";sleep 1; echo "'.$FTPpassword.'") | passwd $FTPUserName');
```

Instead of **$FTPUserName** , if I send username **test** as :

```
shell_exec('(echo "'.$FTPpassword.'";sleep 1; echo "'.$FTPpassword.'") | passwd test');
```

it is updating password of the user "test". 
Anyone know how to change the password of a user using shell_exec?

Regards,
Sowmya

Answer (score 0):

Use `--stdin` flag. This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the new password from standard input, which can be a pipe.

`shell_exec("echo $FTPpassword | passwd $FTPUserName --stdin");`